# ImageView setMatrix only work on image not canvas

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, android-canvas

I am using ImageView with PhotoView library that support zooming and panning.

Right now I am extending the ImageView so i can draw on canvas . Currently i Have setImageResource setting a drawable of a map and In onDraw(canvas); i am drawing some line over a path then drawing that over the canvas.

The problem is when i try zooming, the image zooms perfectly but not the drawing that was drawn over the canvas. it just stays in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
path.transform(getImageMatrix());
```